# What can "ordinary" Stack Overflow users do to support the moderator strike?

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderation-strike

How can the Stack Overflow community support its moderators as they strike?

Comment: Related / Cross site duplicate: [Would the striking moderators welcome a user strike? Should we, the users, go on strike?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390412/would-the-striking-moderators-welcome-a-user-strike-should-we-the-users-go-on), the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390427) by [Starship](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1142965/starship-on-strike) quotes what you can do

Comment: See [the letter you signed today](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/), under "I am not a moderator on any Stack Exchange site, how can I help?". Doubt you'll get more ideas here.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack I signed the letter I found *by chance after wondering what I could since the strike began*. I posted this to help like-minded users. I’m making it a wiki as it should be.

Comment: Darn it! I guess I’m not qualified to make it a wiki.

Comment: I see strike, I upvote.

Comment: Thanks, @Samuel; you are very supportive of the strike.

Comment: Are you just talking about moderation? It is all voluntary anyway so you could stop doing any kind of moderation (votes/comments/edits, etc), regardless of strike.

Comment: @SamuelLiew well, we're in the gray zone here.

Comment: @TheTridentGuysupportsUkraine Only moderators can make a **question** a wiki, and they are........ well - on strike...

Comment: Did you call for me, @ShadowWizardStrikesBack?

Comment: @Cody your zone is needed. :-D

Comment: @Cody Since you are already summoned. Can you please post an answer that explains which flags are still encouraged (custom mod flags) and which are not. I can post it but your answer would have more weight than me saying that moderators suggest we still continue to flag posts that need custom moderator flags.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Not all moderation work is done by moderators. In fact [most is not](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/).

To help the strike you could abstain from some/all of the community curation or moderation tasks, including voting, editing, [reviewing](https://stackoverflow.com/review), or flagging. I would still upvote useful posts/accept useful answers either way, as there is no reason to ignore the efforts of helpful contributors. But much of the spam and non-answers is deleted by ordinary users flagging or voting to delete them from review.

The purpose of the strike is to put pressure on the management to [change their ways](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389811/1377755). The less the moderation, either by moderators or by users, the more problematic content will go unmoderated, and the more the management will feel the effects as the quality of their site declines.

Comment: I would personally like to add something for voting, still upvote posts, as users providing helpful content should still be rewarded

Answer (score 38):

You can start by signing the [strike letter](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/) which suggests some actions:

> **I am not a moderator on any Stack Exchange site, how can I help?**
>
> Even if you are not a moderator you can participate in the strike by:
>
> - Not voting on posts
> - Not submitting edits
> - Not reviewing in the review queues
> - Not commenting
> - Not flagging posts

A note about flagging: If the post needs moderator attention, flag it with the custom flag, as these will build up, pressuring SO.

Comment: But if we do that how is [so] supposed to see the impact of no moderation if the edit queues and the flag queues aren't increasing?

Comment: @user692942 Some types of flags automatically remove content if multiple users flag the content. If you don't flag then such problematic content will stay on sites longer. for instance if you don't flag spam, then it will not be dealt with promptly and company does not want that.

Comment: It has been suggested by moderators that we keep flagging posts that require custom mod flags as those need to be handled manually and they don't expire. Those flags will keep accumulating so they also put the pressure on company.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar that probably would be a good answer on its own