# Should I serial downvote ChatGPT answers?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, chatgpt

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260841/11002), legitimate serial downvoting is pointless because it will just get reversed.

When I see a user who has posted a ChatGPT generated answer I always look at their other recent answers. I flag them, if they are also ChatGPT, but should I downvote too?

Comment: SE management wants to embrace AI here, moderators [are on strike](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425000/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an) and won't process flags so I would just let them be.

Comment: @TadeuszKopecforUkraine That is [bad advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424910/does-the-policy-change-for-ai-generated-content-affect-users-who-want-to-flag):  _"You should continue to flag content that you think is not appropriate and not suitable for the site, using your best judgment. It is the consensus of the mod team that regardless of what policies staff adopts, flags that are accurate and raised in good faith will not be declined by the moderator team."_

Comment: @E_net4isonstrike Counterpoint: [What can "ordinary" Stack Overflow users do to support the moderator strike?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425277/9952196)

Comment: flag/vote the answers on their own merit rather than judging them for being generated by chatgpt (or any tool)

Comment: @Shawn That's a distraction. Sure, you can invite them to participate in the strike, but the intent to perform some kind of curation on a problem is already presented here. As such, the advice applies, to whosoever wishes to continue engaging in moderation activities, with special emphasis on the fact that moderators being on strike is not an excuse to give up on casting flags primarily over the fear of them not being handled.

Comment: Just two comments: you cannot be sure that they are ChatGPT answers (except in some super obvious cases) and they may actually be factually correct.

Comment: A lot of comments here about voting based on the content quality vs the fact they are generative AI answers... If the content of the answer is good enough that it doesn't matter if it's ChatGPT (or another LLM/GenAI tool), then this wouldn't even be a discussion. The problem with the majority of these answers that I flag and downvote is that the content is almost always too generic, including things like "*make sure you've done A, B and/or C, then check D. If all of those are ok, then do E, ...*". The answer _might_ correctly identify the issue, but a lot of it is useless noise. My 2¢ anyway.

Comment: It is frustrating when valid use of tools results in a voting reversal because one person is abusing the site... but that's not gonna be fixed. Don't waste votes that are just gonna get reversed.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution if it's obvious enough that the content is GPT, then it's not really relevant if they happen to miraculously be correct. It's still worth the flag under current guidelines/policy. (these flags don't age away, so there's no risk of these flags just going away due to the strike; mods will be able to handle them later.)

Comment: @KevinB I was more thinking about the voting part.

Comment: [All use of generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT and other LLMs) is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1). If someone is posting large amounts of content with from GPT they should summarily experience an extended ban. Make sure that you can verify it is actually sourced from GPT and then flag it.

Comment: @zurgeg sort of (I linked to an answer to that question) but I was interested in whether there was any difference in advice in the context of ChatGPT.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Certainly, if it's not helpful/useful, downvote the answer you found through your normal use of the site. Also make sure to flag the post denoting that you feel the content is ChatGPT content and explain why.

If you then want to review the user's other posts, that's up to you. Previously, when I flagged such answers, I found that moderators often reviewed the user's other posts anyway as users that post one ChatGPT answer will often post more. As such you might find that helping the mods and listing several posts that all appear to be AI generated in your flag is better than just the one in the flag (not that these things are enforceable right now). This might also be preferable to the mods than many flags (one on each post, but I'm not a mod so I can't tell you if this is true).

As for downvoting any other ChatGPT posts, this is likely (a little) frowned upon you aren't really downvoting the content anymore but targeting the user (because they've posted a bunch of ChatGPT content). Votes are meant to be against the content, not the user. If you truly think the post is that bad, then downvote but just remember that downvoting many of a user's posts could result in those votes being reversed and then your votes were meaningless, even if all the content was bad.

Comment: Unwise to think I cannot defeat the algorithm.

Comment: I always go through the other posts, to satisfy myself that the first question was ChatGPT generated. I only flag when I'm very sure, and in cases where a user has other recent answers they have only ever made me more certain, but it's theoretically possible that they might make me change my mind, so I'm not exactly going through the other answers to "target the user", although the effect is indistinguishable. Thanks for the idea of linking to several answers in a single flag -- that hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: I've always completely disagreed that if you find a user and you look through their content and downvote it, that you're "targeting the user". I'm still voting on the content - I've just found a massive source of bad content. Why wouldn't we want to moderate that content!? I know it's a longstanding policy, and it's difficult to discern that from revenge downvoting...but I wish there was a way for us to prevent revenge downvoting while still allowing us to downvote all bad content we come across.

Comment: @ThomA according to current SO policy "All use of generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT1 and other LLMs) is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow." https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1 So flagging/downvoting all user's questions/answers that legitimately look like ChatGPT generated is not "targeting the user" by following SO policy I would say

Comment: Flagging & downvoting are different things, @Ivan .

Comment: @Ivan: Flagging - yes. Downvoting - no. Downvoting will get reversed as serial voting, and if you repeat it often enough you'll probably get suspended. The proper treatment of AI-generated content is flagging for moderator attention.

Comment: @mason *I've always completely disagreed that if you find a user and you look through their content and downvote it, that you're "targeting the user"* - I don't think many people will disagree with you, you're among friends here. The automated processes on the other hand are too stupid to be able to make the distinction between good intent and bad intent. And those automated processes are a necessary evil given the throughput of this site.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think downvoting all the posts that one is confident are ChatGPT from a single user is wrong. If you're doing it because you're confident that it's ChatGPT content, then you're not voting on a person. You're voting on content and on posts through which a user has made a repeated *practice* of breaking a community policy, which is featured in the sidebar and written in the Help Center. Also, add to that the fact that every single person I've seen post ChatGPT has failed to meet [our referencing requirements](/help/referencing) (which a CM has affirmed applies to referencing ChatGPT content network-wide ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385002/997587))).

(The line is crossed if you start downvoting content of theirs that you are not confident are written in part by ChatGPT. Don't do that. *That's* voting on a person)

There can be possible benefits to doing this too: it can contribute to an answer ban, which is great, because then the *system* starts helping with rate-limiting (which is one of the main concerns with ChatGPT content- that the influx is unmanageable).

It's up to you if you want to downvote every post that you are confident is ChatGPT from a single user. But if you do, you're probably going to need to space it out over several days to avoid getting "serial voting reversed". <sup><sub>In an effort to avoid teaching someone who actually wants to do serial downvoting, I'm not going to say what rate to downvote at to avoid "serial voting reversed".</sub></sup>

Comment: "You're voting on content" on the provenance of the content not on the content itself, I'd say. If you would really only vote on content it wouldn't matter if it was ChatGPT or you or me.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution, fair point. The source of the content is most of what breaks the policy. I think it's legitimate to downvote something that breaks a policy.